# Mysqli LIKE not working with apostrophe?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use my mysqli function to search the database for a certain string with a ' (apostrophe) it never finds a result, although it is exactly the same in the databse.

For example: I search for: dawn's, this gets escaped through real_escape to: dawn\'s and this is the same as in the database (it's put in escaped as well in the database). But still it does not give me a result.

This is the code I use:

> ```
>       $mysqli = goConnect();
>         $query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($query);
>         if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'"))){
>             http_response_code(400);
>             echo "<p class='results'>Cannot prepare the statement, please try again later.</p>";
>         }
>         echo $query;
>         if($stmt->execute()){
> ```

Why doesn't this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysqli doesn't have a LIKE operator and Mysql LIKE works with *any* characters, including apostrophe.

> and this is the same as in the database (it's put in escaped as well in the database).

This is what you are doing wrong. It shouldn't be the same in the database. It should be stored **as is.**

Besides, you should always, always ALWAYS use placeholders to substitute variables in the query. Were you using them, you'd never encounter a problem like this.

So, first change this code to

```
$mysqli = goConnect();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE ?");
$query = "%$query%";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
```

And then change your insert code accordingly, to make it add not a single extra character to the data.

Comment: There's a typo in your code at line 4 ($srmr) but nevertheless it worked great, thank you!